# Parallelizing LibTomMath's Karatsuba impl. with OpenMP failed

Tags: c, multithreading, recursion, parallel-processing, openmp

I thought I'll give OpenMP a try before I roll it myself but I (it?) failed quite miserably.

The Karatsuba multiplying and squaring needed a small change to recurse to itself instead of to the common multiplication branches in `bn_mp_mul.c` and the addition of the OpenMP pragmas.

Changes for Karatsuba multiplication as a diff (squaring is done in the same manner) to [LibTomMath master](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/tree/master):

```
diff -rtbBw libtommath-master-original/bn_mp_mul.c libtommath-master/bn_mp_mul.c
32a34,37
> #ifdef USE_OPEN_MP
> #include <omp.h>
>          #pragma omp parallel
>          #pragma omp master
33a39,41
> #else
>          res = mp_karatsuba_mul(a, b, c);
> #endif
diff -rtbBw libtommath-master-original/bn_mp_karatsuba_mul.c  libtommath-master/bn_mp_karatsuba_mul.c 51a52,54
> #ifdef USE_OPEN_MP
>    int e1,e2;
> #endif
57c60,62
< 
---
>    if (B < KARATSUBA_MUL_CUTOFF) {
>       return mp_mul(a,b,c);
>    }
120c125,135
<    if (mp_mul(&x0, &y0, &x0y0) != MP_OKAY)
---
> #ifdef USE_OPEN_MP
> #include <omp.h>
>    #pragma omp task shared(x0y0)
>    e1 = mp_karatsuba_mul(&x0, &y0, &x0y0);
>    #pragma omp task shared(x1y1)
>    e2 = mp_karatsuba_mul(&x1, &y1, &x1y1);
>    #pragma omp taskwait
>    if ((e1 != MP_OKAY) || (e2 != MP_OKAY))
>       goto X1Y1;
> #else
>    if (mp_karatsuba_mul(&x0, &y0, &x0y0) != MP_OKAY)
122c137
<    if (mp_mul(&x1, &y1, &x1y1) != MP_OKAY)
---
>    if (mp_karatsuba_mul(&x1, &y1, &x1y1) != MP_OKAY)
123a139
> #endif
130,131d145
<    if (mp_mul(&t1, &x0, &t1) != MP_OKAY)
<       goto X1Y1;          /* t1 = (x1 + x0) * (y1 + y0) */
132a147,157
> #ifdef USE_OPEN_MP
> #include <omp.h>
>    #pragma omp task shared(t1)
>    e1 = mp_karatsuba_mul(&t1, &x0, &t1);
>    #pragma omp taskwait
>    if (e1 != MP_OKAY)
>       goto X1Y1;
> #else
>    if (mp_karatsuba_mul(&t1, &x0, &t1) != MP_OKAY)
>       goto X1Y1;          /* t1 = (x1 + x0) * (y1 + y0) */
> #endif
diff -rtbBw libtommath-master-original/makefile  libtommath-master/makefile
17c17,19
< CFLAGS += -O3 -funroll-loops
---
> #CFLAGS += -O3 -funroll-loops
> # the oficial macro is _OPENMP
> CFLAGS += -g3 -O3  -funroll-loops -fopenmp -DUSE_OPEN_MP
```

Using OpenMP's `task` as recommended by many for such a recursive function. A test with computing log(2) to 50,000 bits (with LibTomFloat) for one thread (by adding `num_threads(1)` after the `parallel`) gave the expected result on an AMD A8-6600K (with gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4 and Kernel Linux debian2 3.16.0-38-generic, all for 64-bit).

```
real    0m7.748s
user    0m7.728s
sys 0m0.013s
```

But with more threads? Well...with two threads

```
real    0m8.025s
user    0m14.936s
sys 0m0.060s
```

and with four threads

```
real    0m14.198s
user    0m48.224s
sys 0m0.109s
```

You can see the CPUs sweating in a graphing system-monitor but to no avail here.

I used the atanh() method to compute the constant log(2) in Libtomfloat and implemented the calculation of the acoth() with a binary splitting algorithm. *That* recursion works (switched off for the test above) and is also implemented with OpenMP's `task` in the same way as for the Karatsuba recursion. It does not gain much for log(2) (about 5%), but it gains at least *something* although the 5% are quite close to the statistical error.

So, what did I do wrong here?

**EDIT**

I ran some more tests to try the overhead as suggested by RichardBruce. With the Karatsube set to 250 (was 120 not 48, sorry RichardBruce) I get some optimum for Karatsuba with 1.1 min. real time (for 200k bits) for one and four threads and 1.5min. user time for four threads: no gain. With the cutoff set to 500 I get 1.5 min. real time for one thread and  1.3 with four threads and 2.3 min. user time with four threads: a relative gain but an absolute loss.

I really didn't expect so much overhead from OpenMP. So is it handrolled pthreads or does anybody find a grave error?

Comment: I cant really tell from the diff, but how much work does each task have? To pay off the overhead of threading you will need ~100,000's of cycles of work in each task

Comment: Cutoff is at 48 for mult. and 120 for sqr.. Do you really think it is the overhead? I know that threading in Linux is not as lightweight as elsewhere but 10^5 ops per thread?

Comment: My number came from an older versions of Intel's Thread Building Blocks documentation. It feels about right in my experience, you need quite a few cycle of work to use threading

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I didn't measure anything I just ran some simple Real-World-Tests(TM), expected from my experience with pthreads a small loss at most and was so baffled by the extremely large losses that I *really* thought I made something wrong. I took a short glimpse at libgomp and saw a lot of reasons for a large overhead, especially the large safety net that eats a lot. But implementing the thing by hand with pthreads is complicated, tedious, and error-prone, so OpenMP was definitely worth a try.